# C# Run Powershell command with command as parameter

Tags: c#, powershell, command, hyper-v

I want to use commands as Parameter in C# but I keep getting errors. The following Powershell command is what I need:

```
$hg = Get-SCVMHostGroup -Name 'ClusterName'
$hp = Get-SCHardwareProfile -ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Get-SCVMHostRating -VMName 'TESTVM' -CPUPriority 8 -MemoryPriority 5 -DiskPriority 3 - 
NetworkPriority 1 -DiskSpaceGB 0 -VMHostGroup $hg -HardwareProfile $hp
```

I tried powershell to Invoke the first two commands and then use this as parameter but then I get an error:

> {"Cannot bind parameter 'VMHostGroup'. Cannot convert the value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.HostGroup" to type "Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.HostGroup"."}

The code:

```
powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Runspace = runspace;

Command getVmHostRating = new Command("Get-SCVMHostRating");
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("VMName", "TESTVM");
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("CPUPriority", 8);
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("MemoryPriority", 5);
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("DiskPriority", 3);
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("NetworkPriority", 1);
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("DiskSpaceGB", 0);
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("VMHostGroup", resultSCVMHostGroup);
getVmHostRating.Parameters.Add("HardwareProfile", resultSCHardwareProfile);
powershell.Commands.AddCommand(getVmHostRating);

results = powershell.Invoke();
```

In powershell the following code also works so I can manage to get this in C# it would also be ok:

```
Get-SCVMHostRating -VMName 'TESTVM' -CPUPriority 8 -MemoryPriority 5 -DiskPriority 3 -NetworkPriority 1 -DiskSpaceGB 0 -VMHostGroup (Get-SCVMHostGroup -Name 'ClusterName') -HardwareProfile (Get-SCHardwareProfile -ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where did `resultSCVMHostGroup` and `resultSCHardwareProfile` come from?

Comment: Hello, the variables (commands) are invoked earlier for exmaple the resultSCVMHostGroup :

                // Get SCVMHost Group
                powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                Command getSCVMHostGroup = new Command("Get-SCVMHostGroup");
                getSCVMHostGroup.Parameters.Add("Name", "ClusterName");
                powershell.Commands.AddCommand(getSCVMHostGroup);

                dynamic resultSCVMHostGroup = powershell.Invoke();

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AddScript()` instead.  This way you do not have to deal with getting and using the VMHostGroup and SCHardwareProfile in C#, just let powershell handle it

```
string SCHardwareProfileId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string ClusterName = "ClusterName";
powershell.AddScript(@$"Get-SCVMHostRating -VMName 'TESTVM' -CPUPriority 8 -MemoryPriority 5 -DiskPriority 3 -NetworkPriority 1 -DiskSpaceGB 0 -VMHostGroup (Get-SCVMHostGroup -Name '{ClusterName}') -HardwareProfile (Get-SCHardwareProfile -ID '{SCHardwareProfileId}')");
results = powershell.Invoke();
```